# Why does a char* parameter get changed to a VARIANT_BOOL* in a com call?

Tags: import, idl

I have a VS2017 solution which was converted from VC6. It has 42 C++ projects that compile without error, with one unusual anomaly.

Project A is an .exe project which has a COM interfaces. The interface is  defined in project A's A.odl file. When project A is build it generates the expected A.tlb file. Both the .exe and .tlb files a moved to a common Bin directory. Project B is also an .exe project that uses project A's interface with an #import "..\Bin\A.tlb" directive.

When I clean the solution, delete the common Bin directory, and rebuild, project B fails with the following message:

HRESULT A::IA::raw_IsSameProject(BSTR,VARIANT_BOOL *); cannot convert argument 2 from 'char *' to 'VARIANT_BOOL *'

The actual code that generates the error is:

```
char chResult = 0;
if (S_OK != pIA->raw_IsProjectLoaded(&chResult)) ...
```

At this point if I build only project B, the error goes away.

Here is the relevant content of the various files before the second build of project A. (Files A.tlh and A.tli are in project B's Debug directory):

```
A.odl   boolean IsProjectLoaded();
A.tlb   char IsProjectLoaded();
A.tlh   VARIANT_BOOL IsProjectLoaded();
        HRESULT raw_IsProjectLoaded (VARIANT_BOOL * _result = 0);
A.tli   inline VARIANT_BOOL ITndrtData::IsProjectLoaded ( ) {
            VARIANT_BOOL _result = 0;
            _com_dispatch_method(...);
            return _result;
        }
        inline HRESULT ITndrtData::raw_IsProjectLoaded (VARIANT_BOOL* _pr){ 
            return _com_dispatch_raw_method(...);
        }
```

After building only project B for the second time:

```
A.tlh   char IsProjectLoaded();
        HRESULT raw_IsProjectLoaded (char * _result = 0);
A.tli   inline VARIANT_BOOL ITndrtData::IsProjectLoaded ( ) {
            char _result = 0;
            _com_dispatch_method(...);
            return _result;
        }
        inline HRESULT ITndrtData::raw_IsProjectLoaded ( char * _presult ) {
            return _com_dispatch_raw_method(...);
        }
```

After the second build of project B, the VARIANT_BOOL parameter changes to the expected char. The relevant type parameter in the _com_dispatch methods also change from VT_BOOL* to a char*.

Project B has a reference to project A. Of the 42 projects being build, project A is the 12th project to build and project B is the 21st.

Questions:

- Why does project B use a VARIANT_BOOL parameter after the 1st build
  but the correct char after the 2nd build of only project B?
- Why does A.odl specify a boolean return type for the
  IsProjectLoaded() method but in A.tlb it has changed it to a char?
- Is this some artifact of using and odl file vs the newer idl format?
  (I haven't learned enough about IDL files yet to attempt to convert.)

Answer (score 0):

After posting the question, I did a close review of the build output and found the problem. There are several circular references among the projects in this solution. To handle this, several Circular_Build projects were created which only create a project's .tlb file using MIDL to compile the project's IDL or ODL file. ProjeA'ct A has a Circular_Build project, which I thought I had removed. While looking over the build output I noticed that this Circular_Build project was still being built after both project A and B had been build. Removing this Circular_Build project got rid of the anomaly.

That still leave the question of why A's Circular_Build project creates a .tlb file that uses the char* parameter while A's normal build creates a .tlb file that uses the VARIANT_BOOL* parameter. Will do some more research and post answer if I figure it out.